# How many facebook fan page I can create?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I need to create facebook fan page more than 1000 for my client. How many fan page limited I can create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of pages which can be administered by a single user. If you're creating all of these pages to represent individual branches of a store (for example) Facebook may be able to bulk-import the details for you and set up a parent/child relationship between the branches and the brand.
If you don't have a sales contact in Facebook, https://www.facebook.com/business/contact.php is the form to contact them

Comment: All the pages I want to create are different business around 5000 pages using only one Facebook account. Is there any problem in the future ?

Comment: I really wouldn't advise having only a single user adminstering that many pages in case their account is ever unavailable or they lose their password, etc - I'd recommend having at least 2 admins per page.but there's no technical reason a single user can't be the administrator of that many pages

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of any such limitations